# How to disable “Ctrl+Shift+J” shortcut on a MacBook Pro’s Japanese keyboard?

Tags: macos, macbook, shortcuts, japanese

Is there any way to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> shortcut on Mac Japanese keyboard?

As you can see from this [article](https://nihongoperapera.com/typing-in-japanese/mac-keyboard-shortcuts.html) it switches to hiragana

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> switch to hiragana input

I’m on Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) and  didn’t install any software for “Japanese input method.”

Here is a pic of the keyboard. I live in Japan a I bought Mac with a Japanese keyboard.

[image]

My System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources

[image]

Comment: @techraf thank you for your comment, I updated my question - please look again.

Comment: I am writing on exactly the same keyboard now and I don't quite understand the problem. Do you want to disable (some) action that is bound to the key combination to enable switching to hiragana, or do you want to disable the shortcut for switching to hiragana to enable some other action? In my case Ctrl+Shift+J does exactly nothing.

Comment: What is your System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources setting?

Comment: @techraf I updated my question(added photo). I use Ctrl+Shift+J in VIM - And it does work, but then after action is done it switches me to hiragana :) so I have to switch back to english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can disable a shortcut using a free utility [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/). The instructions to do it are already in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18765462/2947502). This should work for your virtual machine, but if it was a different app's shortcut that you wanted to use and you just disabled the key combination globally with BTT, it would disable also for that app.

Also the visual hints for the shortcuts (⌃⇧J)  will remain present in the toolbar, they just won't work, so if you later forget that you disabled it and try to figure out why something does not work, you would have a hard time.

---

Second, I would recommend using [Google Japanese Input](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/japaneseinput/eula.html) which is more feature-rich than Apple's native input method. It does not use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> shortcut, but on the other hand it uses other shortcuts, so it is more like shifting the problem rather than solving it.

---

Third, you can create your own custom keyboard layout with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele). Essentially it also disables all the shortcuts introduced by Apple or Google Japanese input methods.

You still need to have Japanese input (either Apple or Google) present for it to work, but then you can use only two keys to switch: <kbd>英数</kbd> for your own, and <kbd>かな</kbd> for Japanese (hiragana with word replacement).

I don't know how much sense it would make for Russian though, as you use a whole different layout and probably need to switch between three layouts. I created my own [layout](https://github.com/techraf/mac-poljap-keyboard) for Polish-programmers layout, which is essentially an "extended" English keyboard with national characters typed using right <kbd>⌘</kbd>. So for me this method reduced 3 layouts to 2.

Still (in addition to having no shortcuts) you might utilize the method to define shortcuts to long vowels in Hepburn, like: ō or ū; or make an English layout matching Russian for non-alphabet characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your awesome help. I didn't know about  BetterTouchTool & Google Japanese Input. And your layout will be a great example for me to customize my own layout. Again, thank you very much mate, your answer does help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with Keyboard Maestro. After I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> It also changes language back to english by pressing on <kbd>英数</kbd> == `JIS Eisu` in Keyboard Maestro. This method is not free, so if someone know other way—please let me know.
 [image]